# Determining whether a given matrix is regular

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The definition of a regular matrix if some power of the matrix gives a matrix with all positive entries then it is said to be regular. Is there a way of finding this "power" without having to go on a trial and error basis? Any other ways of finding if a matrix is regular?Thanks

Comment: There's one criterion of a non-regular matrix. A regular matrix has a positive eigenvalue with the corresponding eigenvector having all non-negative coordinates. If your matrix doesn't have this property, it can't be regular.

Comment: See this post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216015/understanding-regular-matrices