# Regular matrix - LU decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

I´ve the following math problem:

Determime for which {$x,y,z$} is the matrix $A$ regular and then find the LU decomposition.

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 & 1 \\
  x & y & z \\
  x^2 & y^2 &z^2\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Determining when it is regular... I have tried using the definition of regular matrix. For instance that its rows and columns must be linearly independent but that didn´t take me far.
We know the rank is 3 but I am still not sure how to proceed if we want to make sure we find all solutions. Also I would appreciate approach without using determinant.

Thank you.

Comment: What definition of regular matrix are you using? regular  = invertible ?  or regular = http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216015/understanding-regular-matrices ?

Comment: Not that the definition really helps me here, at least not that I can see..
We can say that regular matrix is invertible matrix which is when there exists some matrix $X$ (inverse of $A$) such that $AX = XA = I_n$.. In this particular case $I_3$. Knowing that, if I now use the definition of matrix multiplication we get 9 equations with 12 variables? That doesn´t help me much, does it?

Comment: Any hints or ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to find the [Row Echelon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form) from of your matrix, we ma proceed as follows:

$R_2 \leftarrow  R_2-xR_1 \text{ and } R_3 \leftarrow  R_3-x^2R_1  $ implies  $$ \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 & 1 \\
  0 & y-x & z-x \\
  0 & y^2-x^2 &z^2-x^2\\
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 & 1 \\
  0 & y-x & z-x \\
  0 & (y-x)(y+x) &z^2-x^2\\
\end{pmatrix}  $$
Now  $R_3 \leftarrow R_3 -(x+y) R_2$ implies
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 & 1 \\
  0 & y-x & z-x \\
  0 & 0 &(z^2-x^2)-(z-x)(x+y)\\
\end{pmatrix} 
Note that this last matrix and the original matrix  $A$ have the same [Rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_%28linear_algebra%29#Rank_from_row_echelon_forms), and  $A$ is regular (invertible) if its rank is  three. This last matrix has rank three if  $ y-x\ neq 0 $  and  $(z^2-x^2)-(z-x)(x+y) \neq 0 $  i.e. $x \neq  y$ and  $ (z-x)(z+x-x-y) \neq  0 $,   i.e. $ x \neq  y$  and  $z \neq  y$  and  $z\neq x$.